# XML grid won't expand

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have a parent grid ("Output") hosting 2 smaller grids.

The smaller grids MainDisplay (which basically shows an image in a ViewBox that I want to take all of the horizontal space except for 300 in the other of the 2 sub grids) and Input (a fixed width of 300, which actually works as expected).

My problems are:

1) The parent grid does not consume all the horizontal space. I want the extra space to go to the grid with the ViewBox.

I have sprinkled 'HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"' and 'Width="*"' all over, but it won't take up all the space on the screen!

2) I have code behind to grab the width/height of the image. Unless I explicitly set the height, width the code behind tries to grab the height and width and crashes ... but if I set the width/height explicitly I'm afraid it's not going to grab the available space.

Here is the code:

```
<Grid x:Name="Output" Background="#1D1D1D" Margin="0,2,0,-2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="MainDisplay" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Viewbox Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MinWidth="400" MinHeight="400" x:Name="Scenario4ImageContainer" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Image x:Name="Scenario4Image" PointerPressed="Scenario4Image_PointerPressed" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Width="300" x:Name="Input" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Text="Tools" />
            <Grid Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="230" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="DarkSlateGray"
                        Content="Draw Mandelbrot set" Click="DrawMandelbrotSet_Click" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Scenario4DrawMandelbrotDescription" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                           Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Text." />

                <Button x:Name="Scenario4SetSourceButton" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Content="Load image using SetSource" Click="LoadImageUsingSetSource_Click" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Scenario4SetSourceDescription" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                           Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Text." />

                <Button x:Name="Scenario4LoadImageButton" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Content="Load image using PixelBuffer" Click="LoadImageUsingPixelBuffer_Click" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="Scenario4LoadImageDescription" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" 
                           Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Text="Text." />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but try `"*"` instead of `"Auto"` in your first column definition:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Awesome! I had (wrongly) thought they were the same. I guess I am reading through this book I have too quickly :(